Accessing a file outside tomcat directory structure
I have a file structure not under my control. I need to access a file from within my ServletContextListener which is outside the tomcat directory.
This is my code:
// access a random file to get full path
URL basePathURL = MyContextListener.class.getResource("/somereference.txt");
String path = URLDecoder.decode(basePathURL.getPath(), "UTF-8");

// get relevant part of the path
String tomcatServerDir = path.substring(0, path.indexOf("server"));

// get the parent
Path myRequiredFileDirPath = Paths.get(tomcatServerDir).getParent();

// form path to required file
String confPath = credentialsFileDirPath.toString() + "/fileToAccess.txt";
File myFile = new File(confPath);

// code to read the file here

This gives the following error:
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/MyApp/
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)

The directory structure is this:
Path to somereference.txt: C:\MyApp\server\tomcat\webapps\mywebapp\WEB-INF\classes\somereference.txt
Path to fileToAccess.txt: C:\MyApp\fileToAccess.txt
The path to MyApp can differ based on where the app is deployed. However, the structure within MyApp won't change.
What would be the best way to read fileToAccess.txt from within the ServletContextListener class?

Path /C:/MyApp/ (from exception message) looks incorrect. Maybe you should strip off trailing / char?

ServletContext.getResourceAsStream() will load a file from a given path relative to the root of the WAR file. Something like:
ServletContext ctx;
InputStream configStream = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/somereference.txt");


i don't want to read somereference.txt. I want to read fileToAccess.txt, which is outside. I am using somereference.txt to get the full path, riding which, I want to reach fileToAccess.txt. But unable to do as of now.

Apologies, my bad, I misread your second part of the question
